# "Piece of mind"

Tags: idioms, errors, eggcorn

I was interested in the following sentence which appeared in an article titled “[Personal Health: Diagnosing PMS](http://www.nytimes.com/specials/women/warchive/960828_1114.html)” in The New York Times, Women's Health, (August 28, 1996).

> Experts insist that no woman should now have to risk her job, her
>   personal relationships or her **piece of mind** because of premenstrual
>   disturbances.

I'm not particularly convinced in order to this "piece of mind" usage. Am I wrong?

Or, perhaps, in the above sentence "piece of mind" assumes an idiomatic meaning that I am not able to understand. Can someone clarify this question?

Comment: 'peace of mind' or 'a piece of her mind', whichever was intended, do not have anything particular connected with women's health.

Comment: Yeah, until I haven't read the answer of JeffSahol I thought that 'piece of mind' were a possible idiomatic phrase related to women's health, but I'm ready to change the title, now. Do you have any suggestion? I'm relatively new here. @Mitch

Comment: As indicated, it's a straightforward typo/spelling error for *peace*. Too Localised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a typographical error, for "[peace of mind](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peace+of+mind)". The two words, *piece* and *peace*, are pronounced the same. Nothing to do with women's health *per se*.

Comment: And I bet the author gave them a piece of her mind when it was published.

Comment: Now *that's* a peace of work...

Comment: Could you expand upon your answer? What is the reason of this trivial error? Pheraps piece and peace are similar in pronunciation. Are they?

Comment: @RégisRoux yes, that is exactly it.  *Piece* and *peace* are [homophones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone).

Comment: +1, but I suspect the error was **not** typographical. As CN said, `Peace` and `Piece` are homonyms for most of us Americans, and that phrase is pronounced more than it is written. Most likely, the author actually thinks `piece` is the correct word. Mistaking homonyms (and near homonyms) in phrases is my favorite way to tell how much an author reads.

Comment: Agreed that it's probably not a typo but probably an erratum, but considering the subject matter I didn't want the author to (as Andrew mentioned) give me a piece of her mind.

Comment: @JeffSahol Thank you for your answer, it helps me as well but as I am not a native English speaker, Can yo explain the sentence in your answer "Nothing to do with women's health per se." Please

Comment: *per se* is Latin for "in itself". I meant that the phrase is not particularly about women's health.